# Restore multiple transaction log backup from disk

Tags: t-sql, backups

We are receiving transaction log backups from a vendor for a off-site database.  We have already restored the full backup in Standby mode.  we will be receiving multiple transaction log backups everyday.  I need a script to restore the transaction log backups to standby mode.  The script I am trying to use pulls the files into the filelist, but the script is not doing anything and I can't figure out why.

Can someone help me figure this out?

```
USE Master; 
GO  
SET NOCOUNT ON 

-- 1 - Variable declaration 
DECLARE @dbName sysname 
DECLARE @backupPath NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @fileList TABLE (backupFile NVARCHAR(255)) 
DECLARE @lastFullBackup NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @lastDiffBackup NVARCHAR(500) 
DECLARE @backupFile NVARCHAR(500) 

-- 2 - Initialize variables 
SET @dbName = 'Telcor' 
SET @backupPath = 'D:\TelcorLogDump\' 

-- 3 - get list of files 
SET @cmd = 'DIR /b "' + @backupPath + '"'

INSERT INTO @fileList(backupFile) 
EXEC master.sys.xp_cmdshell @cmd 

DECLARE backupFiles CURSOR FOR  
   SELECT backupFile  
   FROM @fileList 
   WHERE backupFile LIKE '%.TRN'  
   AND backupFile LIKE @dbName + '%' 
  -- AND backupFile > @lastFullBackup 

OPEN backupFiles  

-- Loop through all the files for the database  
FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @backupFile  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
   SET @cmd = 'RESTORE LOG [' + @dbName + '] FROM DISK = '''  
       + @backupPath + @backupFile + ''' WITH STANDBY = N''D:\TelcorLogDump\ROLLBACK_UNDO_Telcor.BAK' 
   PRINT @cmd 
   FETCH NEXT FROM backupFiles INTO @backupFile  
END 

CLOSE backupFiles  
DEALLOCATE backupFiles
```

Comment: I figured out why the exec @cmd wasn't working.  I was filtering out the files before it got to the cursor.  Now I have one last problem.  I am getting a message that says Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'D:\TelcorLogDump\ROLLBACK_UNDO_Telcor.BAK'  See below code.  Can someone help me figure out where I'm going wrong with these quote marks?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add two extra ticks at the end:

```
ROM DISK = '''

* @backupPath + @backupFile + ''' WITH STANDBY = N''D:\TelcorLogDump\ROLLBACK_UNDO_Telcor.BAK

'''
```